# Voice to text using python in machine learning

Tags: python

I have experience in python, my current project is about ML/Al. I am planning to build a speech recognition application without using Google's API i.e planning to build from scratch.

Can you please help me out in this regard.
I'm badly stuck without using Google's API the accuracy is too bad to say.
Looking for a solution from all ML experts.

Comment: Sounds like you already have training data and a model set up. Mind sharing what your setup looks like, so you can get more specific help?

Comment: No i don't have a trained model.

Answer (score 0):

@FlyingTeller,
i tried with this piece of code

```
import speech_recognition
import pyttsx3 as p
speech_engine = p.init('sapi5') 
speech_engine.setProperty('rate', 150)


def speak(text):
    speech_engine.say(text)
    speech_engine.runAndWait()


recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()


def listen():
    with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)

    try:
        return recognizer.recognize_sphinx(audio)
    except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError:

        # or: return recognizer.recognize_google(audio)

        print('Could not understand audio')
    except speech_recognition.RequestError as e:
        print('Recog Error; {0}'.format(e))

    return ''


speak('Say something!')
speak('I heard you say ' + listen())
```